# Windows : How to create a self-signed root certificate and a self-signed certificate signed with a self-signed root certificate

Tags: certificate, windows, certificate-authority

How to create a self-signed root certificate and a self-signed certificate signed with a self-signed root certificate.
I tried `New-SelfSignedCertificate` command to create a self-signed certificate but didn't find any option to create a self-signed root certificate and self-signed server certificate signed with a self-signed root certificate.

Comment: I think this question is a better fit for [su], since it's not really about Information Security itself, but rather how to use Windows' built-in tools to achieve a task that is tangentially related to information security. I already voted to migrate the question, so please don't create a duplicate.

Comment: Here is an article is talking about [Generating self-signed certificates on Windows](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/generating-self-signed-certificates-on-windows-7812a600c2d8), please kindly check if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's [a link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-temporary-certificates-for-use-during-development) to create self-signed root certificate and a self-signed certificate from self-signed root certificate.